# Loading data from a web service on app startup

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

In my nativescript app, I need to cache data returned from by a web service. At what exact location do I put the call the get data from my web service to store it in appSettings?

If I put it in the location specified below:

```
applicationOn(launchEvent, function (args: ApplicationEventData) {
    if (args.android) {
        **WEB SERVICE CALL HERE**
    } else if (args.ios !== undefined) {
        // For iOS applications, args.ios is NSDictionary (launchOptions).
        console.log("Launched iOS application with options: " + args.ios);
    }
});
```

it simply does not get executed. No error or no exception.

Comment: Just make the call in some of the lifecycle events of your landing page

Comment: It matters where you have this code. Since you are using Angular, if you put this in `main.ts` it won't be missed. If you want to update data even when app resumes, simply use `resume` event that should cover both startup and resume.